# Not able to get the = Local scope value inside directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

```
<html>
<head>
<title>
</title>
<script src="../../angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

    myApp.controller("empController", function($scope){
        $scope.ename = {nm : "Harry"};
        $scope.changeName = function(){$scope.ename.nm = "Ron";};
    });
    myApp.directive("empDirective", function(){
        return {
            scope : {employeeName : "=myEmpName", nameChange : "&click"},
            template : 'Employee Name is {{employeeName.nm}}. <button ng-click="nameChange()">Change Name</button>'
        };
    });

</script>
</head>

<body ng-app="myApp">

    <div ng-controller="empController">
        <div emp-directive myEmpName="ename" click="changeName()" > </div>
        {{ename.nm}}
    </div>

</body>
```

When I am running the above code I am not getting the employeeName.nm value inside directive. Not sure what I am missing. I am new in AngularJS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your template, change

```
myEmpName
```

to

```
my-emp-name
```

Angular requires hyphen separated attributes in templates and converts them to camel case itself via a process called normalisation.

Comment: No, problem! Also, can you accept the answer if you found it correct? :)